# Learning java and can't figure out y=m*x+b

Tags: java

Creating an Algebra Tutor trying to create random integers to solve y=m*x+b. Searched and found a lot of users have worked with this equation but not with generating a random question to require an answer and check if correct.  This is what I have written so far;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class AlgebraTutor {
  private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++){
          System.out.println("X = " + ((int)(Math.random() * 200) -99));
      }    

      for (int m = 0; m < 1; m++){
          System.out.println("M = " + ((int)(Math.random() * 200) -99));
      }

      for (int b = 0; b < 1; b++){
          System.out.println("B = " + ((int)(Math.random() * 200) -99));
      }

  }
}
```

I believe I'm on the right path with generating numbers between -100 and 100.  I just don't know what to do to move forward with combining them so that I can input an answer to the numbers created.  My best guess was

```
System.out.print("Y = " + m * x + b);
```

But that didn't work the way I thought it would.  I want to be able to input an answer and have it check true or false.  Thanks for any advice to get past this.

Comment: What part do you need help with? Getting user input? Storing the random values for `m`, `x`, and `b` and later using them? Something else? Your loops don't make a lot of sense. You probably want a single loop that repeatedly generates `m`, `x`, and `b`, then obtains user input and checks the answer. (You'll also need a way for the user to indicate that the loop should exit.) Also, if all you need is integers, try creating an instance of `java.util.Random` and using its `nextInt(bound)` method.

Comment: A friend told me of `java.util.Random` but I had never heard of that or how to use it.  I'm assuming there is more benefit to it though.  Would that mean instead of what I used to get x, m, and b I would just create them as `int x = nextInt(100) + 1;` ?

Comment: Since you want numbers between -100 and +100, you'd probably want `int x = rand.nextInt(201) - 100;` (assuming `rand` is your `Random` object and the bounds of -100 and +100 are inclusive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the values in variables for example:

```
int x = ((int)(Math.random() * 200) -99));
```

Also your for loops are unnecessary in that they only run once so you could just run the program instead of looping once.

so in the end your code should be something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class AlgebraTutor {
  private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int x = ((int)(Math.random() * 200) -99);
      int m = ((int)(Math.random() * 200) -99);
      int b = ((int)(Math.random() * 200) -99);
      System.out.println("X = " + x);
      System.out.println("M = " + m);
      System.out.println("B = " + b);
      System.out.println("Y = " + m*x+b);

  }
}
```

And to have it check the answer if it is true or false you would have to do something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class AlgebraTutor {
  private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int x = ((int)(Math.random() * 200) -99);
      int m = ((int)(Math.random() * 200) -99);
      int b = ((int)(Math.random() * 200) -99);
      int y = m*x+b;
      System.out.println("X = " + x);
      System.out.println("M = " + m);
      System.out.println("B = " + b);
      int INPUT = in.nextInt();
      if(INPUT == y){
         System.out.println("You Got It Right!");
         System.out.println("Y = " + y);
      } else {
         System.out.println("You Got It Wrong :(");
         System.out.println("The Answer was: Y = " + y);

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `println("Y = " + m*x+b)` won't work right, since both `+` operators are *string concatenation*. You need a parenthesis so the second `+` becomes an addition operator: `println("Y = " + (m*x+b))`

Answer (score 0):

The variables x,m and b in your example are in the **scope** of each for-loop but die after the `}` of the loops.

```
int x = (int)(Math.random() * 200) -99); // these variables will live long enough.
int m = (int)(Math.random() * 200) -99);
int b = (int)(Math.random() * 200) -99);

System.out.println("X = " + x);
System.out.println("M = " + m);
System.out.println("B = " + b);


System.out.print("Y = " + m * x + b);
```

This should work, but note to be careful when you try to divide these numbers like "x/b" - you will need a cast to float (google division by integer)